# What's the difference between an Online Analytical Processing (OLAP) database and an Operational Data Store (ODS) database?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Both seem to refer to tables which can be easily analyzed and are updated from the OLTP tables every once in a while.

Comment: Please include your understanding of the difference between "Processing" and "Store"?  The question asks about two things which seem unrelated: "Processing" and "Store".  Please explain how you think they overlap and what confuses you about the difference between "Processing" and "Store".

Comment: I should have appended the term 'database' to each of those terms.

Comment: Please also explain what is confusing about "Processing" and "Store".  Adding database doesn't remove the verbs.  Please explain why the "processing" and "store" are confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle no absolute difference. Those two concepts are orthogonal to each other, they are not mutually exclusive.

OLAP refers either to a type of workload or sometimes to the type of software used for Decision Support applications. ODS is a type of database or subset of some database, typically used as part of a Decisions Support solution.